# Does it make sense to say [v]ませんでしたら instead of [v]なかったら?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, conjugations, negation

I'm wondering whether it makes sense to say [v]ませんでしたら instead of [v]なかったら.

When I googled for that conjugation there were very few results, but since there *were* results, I wonder if people actually use [v]ませんでしたら.

For example http://homepage3.nifty.com/floatingbugs/fishing070216.htm:

> お名前を**聞きませんでしたら**また。。

http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1150782366

> 二回目は私達は帰りに焼肉を食べたので**食べませんでしたら**以後作らなくなりました。

http://blog.zaq.ne.jp/lemongrass/article/707/

> いつまでもアップ**しませんでしたら**、失敗したんやなって思っといてください。

Comment: What I learned about たら construction is that usually something follows after たら, and that can be in a polite form. Putting too many polite constructions together would result in a "politeness overload" (i'm not sure enough of this to post as an answer though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the person probably intended to write

> お名前を聞きませんでしたからまた

which is still wrong. It should not be in polite form, or `ので` should be used instead.

> お名前を聞かなかったから
>   お名前を聞きませんでしたので

Comment: heys btw i've added 2 more examples, they aren't too typo mistakes right?

Comment: The original text is お名前を聞きませんでしたらまた釣り場で会いましたらよろしくです.  I think that でしたら is a typo for でしたが rather than for でしたから.